# Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы файл (.css/.js/.html/.json, любой) у пользователя всегда обновлялся при посещении сайта?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Если пользователь уже один раз зашел на сайт, все последующие разы у него уже будут сохранены базовые файлы сайта (стили, скрипты). В следствии чего, после их обновления на сервере, может случиться что у пользователя остались старые подгруженные файлы.
Есть ли какой-то атрибут или функция JS, которая позволяет заново считывать файл страницы после обновления (будто пользователь нажал ctrl+F5)? Желательно это делать для одного файла чтобы каждый раз не было долгой загрузки.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете добавить генерировать случайный параметр к ссылке, которая загружает стили или js, таким образом браузер не будет кэшировать эти данные

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://mysite/style.css?id=1234">
```